Equivalence of triangulated categories defined by tilting objects.
Let $\mathcal{T}$ be a $k$- linear triangulated category (i.e. a triangulated category whose Homs are k-vector spaces). Suppose we have a tilting object $T \in \mathcal{T}$. Recall, this means that $T$ classically generates $\mathcal{T}$ and Hom$(T, T[l]) = 0$ for all $l \neq 0$.
Define $A := End(T)$, the endomorphism algebra of $T$.
Then, if I understand correctly, there should be an equivalence
$\mathcal{T} \xrightarrow{\sim} D^{b}(A)$.
My question is that I am not sure what this equivalence should be, and whether one needs additional assumptions on the triangulated category $\mathcal{T}$?
For example, if $\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{D}^{b}(R)$ is the bounded derived category over some ring, is the equivalence given by $\mathbb{R}Hom(T,-)$?
I read that maybe this has some connection with tilting theory (whatever that is!), and I am mainly interested in this question because I would like to ultimately understand the triangulated subcategories generated by exceptional objects (recall, strong exceptional sequences give tilting objects in any triangulated category).
Perhaps my question is stated more vaguely than I would like it to be, but I am looking for precise statements and proofs of these statements which I cannot find in the literature (any references would be much appreciated!)
